# Trying to call tape.gradient on a non-persistent tape while it is still active

Tags: tensorflow

Why is TensorFlow giving me the runtime error (in the title)?

I'm using WinPython3.5.4.2 and have installed TensorFlow 1.8.0. I've been following the tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager up to the section titled "Training loop".

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e08164fd8374> in <module>()
 14     for x, y in train_dataset:
 15         # Optimize the model
---> 16         grads = grad(model, x, y)
 17         optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
 18                                   global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())

<ipython-input-7-08164b502799> in grad(model, inputs, targets)
  6     with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  7         loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
----> 8         return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)

C:\[deleted]\WinPython3.5.4.2\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients)
765     flat_grad = imperative_grad.imperative_grad(
766         _default_vspace, self._tape, [target], flat_sources,
--> 767         output_gradients=output_gradients)
768 
769     if not self._persistent:

C:\[deleted]\WinPython3.5.4.2\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(vspace, tape, target, sources, output_gradients)
 61   """
 62   return pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(
---> 63       tape._tape, vspace, target, sources, output_gradients)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

RuntimeError: Trying to call tape.gradient on a non-persistent tape while it is still active.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect in your sample you're invoking `tape.gradient()` within the `with tf.GradientTape()` context as opposed to outside of it. Changing from:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
  return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)
```

to

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
# Notice the change in indentation of the line below
return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)
```

should cause the error to go away.

TensorFlow operations executed within the context of a `GradientTape` are "recorded" so that the recorded computation can be later differentiated.  This recording costs memory (since tensors materialized by intermediate operations have to be kept alive). Invoking `tape.gradient()` within the `GradientTape` context manager would mean that the gradient computation should be recorded as well and tensors created during the gradient computation need to be kept alive. Often this isn't what the user intended - the `tape.gradient()` call is only accidentally inside the context manager, leading to a larger memory footprint than necessary. Hence the error. Though, arguably the error message string isn't particularly well phrased (and I believe will be improved in releases after TensorFlow 1.8).

Quoting from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape)

> By default, the resources held by a `GradientTape` are released as soon as `GradientTape.gradient()` method is called. To compute multiple gradients over the same computation, create a `persistent` gradient tape. This allows multiple calls to the `gradient()` method as resources are released when the tape object is garbage collected.

So, if you really do want to record the gradient computation (for example, to compute second order derivatives), then you could create a persistent tape and keep the `.gradient()` call inside the context manager. For example:

```
x = tfe.Variable(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  y = x * x
  dy = g.gradient(y, x)
  d2y = g.gradient(dy, x)
print(dy)
print(d2y)
```

Eager execution is a relatively new feature in TensorFlow, feedback on it is more than welcome. If you think that the error message could be better (it could be!) and/or the default should be changed (for example, persistent by default and users particularly concerned about memory overheads could explicitly choose a non-persistent tape) - don't hesitate to chime in by providing [feedback on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new)

Hope that helps!

Comment: By regular python behavior the tape in the CORRECTLY running code definitely seems to be out of scope of the with statement. It would cause an error in normal code. But in tensorflow the opposite is true. This behavior of tensorflow is not the behavior that a python coder would expect. Unexpected behavior results in increased development costs.

Comment: You need to explain the unexpected behavior in the documentation and tutorials if this is the behavior you are going to keep. It is not OK that I had to find the explanation for TF behavior using Google and Stackoverflow instead of the TF documentation itself.

Comment: Note sure I follow. The documentation states "Operations are recorded if they are executed within this context manager". In the correctly running code, all  operations to differentiate through are executed within the context manager. The `tape.gradients()` call (that we don't want to differentiate through) is not.

I don't doubt that the documentation could be improved, I'm just not sure I understand your concern here (e.g., what you mean by "error in normal mode"). I'd encourage you to contribute to improved documentation by filing a bug or better yet, sending a pull request to fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to a common misconception that the "with" clause in python causes the object declared in it to go out of scope at the end of the block. It does not. It simply causes `__enter__` and `__exit__` to be executed on that object, which may or may not invalidate it. In this case the "with" clause on the gradient tape simply constructs the object, gives it a var name "g", and starts tracking gradients. `__exit__()` on the gradient tape stops tracking, but does not invalidate / clean up the object itself.